# compilation error. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Here is my small program,

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

Here is my compilation command.

> python myprogram.py

Compilation error,

```
  File "game.py", line 1, in 
    import pygame
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/pygame.py", line 2, in 
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I have pygame installed in my ubuntu, It is installed in

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pygame
```

I found tht from IDLE, If I execute both of this statements, It works fine.

Comment: Where is "game.py" saved? If pygame is in site-packages, but there is also a "pygame.py" in the same folder as "game.py", then the file in the same folder w/ the same name will be imported instead.

Comment: Note that this is not a compiletime error. Importing, like nearly everything else (except parsing) happens at runtime in Python. And `python somefile.py` of course *runs* the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Delete the "pygame.py" file in your Documents folder, it is shadowing the real pygame you've installed.

It looks like you first saved your small test program as "pygame.py", then renamed it to "game.py".

Comment: Oh! It was sily mistake, Its 05:25 AM here, I think I need to sleep. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. *Here is my compilation command*:`python myprogram.py` 
   but you have error in   `File "game.py", line 1, in` oO
2. I was have same problem and solve it by renaming of main .py file. He can't be the same as module i.e **pygame**

Answer (score -2):

Rename pygame.py to another_name_as_pygame.py and this is your new Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
```